# Displaying long text in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I use `EditText` to display long text that can be 600 000 characters long and longer.

For that I set:

```
android:maxLength="10000000"
```

From time to time I select text programmatically using

```
EditText.setSelection(int start, int end)
```

which works and if the selection range is outside the visible window it will be moved to the window very quickly.

However as soon as user starts editing the text the response time will be very long although my phone's memory is 3Gb.

So I started thinking maybe there is no other way than to display text in chunks.

Is there a standard mechanism in Android for displaying a long text in chunks in `EdiText`? So that depending on cursor position or selection and on size of the window the mechanism adds/removes text as needed to/from the beginning or the end so that text in `EditText` doesn't exceed some limit.

I'm curious whether I would reinvent the wheel by implementing it myself.

Comment: how many characters you want to `store`

Comment: @VishalYadav Doesn't matter. The main requirement is that the visible area of EditText is always filled with text depending on cursor position or selection. EditText itself can store as much text as needed to fill the visible area and maybe 100 chars before and after.

Comment: Did you tried this 
`android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"`
`android:maxLines="200"`

Comment: @sunilsunny According to documentation this setting only controls the size of the text field and not the size of the whole available text.